# Correct way of returning data from function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm new to Node so I'm struggling with getting the data from one function to another:

```
//dhtController.js
const dhtSensor = require('node-dht-sensor').promises;

exports.currentTemperature = async () => {
  const rawTemp = await dhtSensor.read(22, 4); // { temperature: 24, humidity: 60 }

  return rawTemp;
};




//dataController.js
const dhtController = require('./dhtController');

...
exports.getAllReadings = (req, res, next) => {
  const currentTemp = dhtController.currentTemperature(); // undefined

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    currentTemp, // undefined
  });
};
...
```

I tried using async/await in dataController as well - no luck.
Old callback-way works, however I rather keep things consistent and use async/await.

Can somebody help me out here? What am I missing? My guess is that in my dataController the results are not in the event loop yet. However 'awaiting' them did not help.

**UPD:**

Guys, thanks, I tried this from the very beginning:

```
exports.getAllReadings = async (req, res, next) => {
  const currentTemp = await dhtController.currentTemperature();

  console.log(JSON.stringify({ currentTemp: new Promise(() => {}) }));
  //{"currentTemp":{}}    

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    message: 'Here we will have all sensors object',
    currentTemp, // empty
  });
};
```

Postman result:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Here we will have all sensors object"
}
```

Comment: You need to add `async` keyword in `getAllReadings` and then use `await` before `dhtController.currentTemperature()`

Comment: Also, `currentTemp` is not `undefined`, it is an instance of [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). If you `JSON.stringify({ currentTemp: new Promise(() => {}) })` you get `"{\"currentTemp\":{}}"`, not `"{}"`, so I'm not sure what leads you to think `currentTemp` is `undefined`

Comment: Tried that earlier:
`exports.getAllReadings = async (req, res, next) => {
  const currentTemp = await dhtController.currentTemperature();` returns 'undefined'

Comment: That's not even possible. `async` functions _always_ return promises, no exceptions. Please produce a [mcve] because I'm certain either you're mistaken, or your example code is not representative of the situation.

Comment: Is `dhtSensor = require('node-dht-sensor')` or `dhtSensor = require('node-dht-sensor').promises`? If it's the former, that's your mistake.

Comment: My bad for not mentioning it earlier, I've required it like this from the start `const dhtSensor = require('node-dht-sensor').promises;`

Comment: The main disconnect at this point is that if `rawTemp` is `{ temperature: 24, humidity: 60 }` then `currentTemp` _must_ be the same given your code. Are you _sure_ there's nothing else relevant you're omitting? I'm asking because what you're currently describing for the code provided isn't just unlikely, it's _impossible_.

Comment: I agree, this doesn't make sense to me as well. dhtController contains only test mode data, as described in the [docs](https://github.com/momenso/node-dht-sensor#test-mode) After that, there's only `currentTemperature()`

Comment: Tried to see if I could install it and reproduce the problem but it appears node-dht-sensor does not support windows.

Answer (score 3):

Since the function you're calling uses an await, you need to make the function you're calling it in async. Which makes sense since you're waiting for a result.

```
exports.getAllReadings = async (req, res, next) => {
  const currentTemp = await dhtController.currentTemperature(); 

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    currentTemp, // undefined
  });
};
```

Comment: Dude, 10 seconds! 

Answer (score 3):

Using `async` and `await` you can make it work:

```
exports.getAllReadings = async (req, res, next) => {
  const currentTemp = await dhtController.currentTemperature(); // undefined

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    currentTemp, // will be defined
  });
};
```